# How to call non-escaping closure inside a local closure?

Tags: swift, closures, swift3

I have a function which looks something like this:

```
func test(closure: () -> ()) {
    let localClosure = { closure() }

    localClosure()
}
```

*This is only an example and does not fully reflect the problem I encountered, obviously here I could have just called `closure` directly!*

It should be clear that in the above code, `closure` cannot escape. However, I get the error:

> Closure use of non-escaping parameter 'closure' may allow it to escape

Now, if `localClosure` was escaping in some way, I'd understand this error, but it doesn't escape. I even tried annotating `localClosure` as `@noescape` (even though that attribute is deprecated in Swift 3), and according to the warning I got:

> @noescape is the **default** and is deprecated

If `localClosure` is, by default, non-escaping, then why can't another non-escaping closure go inside it? Or is this a bug/limitation of the compiler?

Comment: Possibly relevant Q&A (at least w.r.t the compiler's bogus warning about `localClosure` being `@noescape` by default, which it isn't): [Why do closures require an explicit `self` when they're all non-escaping by default in Swift 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433221/why-do-closures-require-an-explicit-self-when-theyre-all-non-escaping-by-defa)

Comment: @Hamish I belive that target thread is actually a perfect dupe mark for this thread (even if it's a slightly different question, the answers to the target also answers this question): the whole discussion (and previous answer) falls apart so a single simple fact once it's clear that non-parameter closures are actually `@escaping` by default. Voting to dupe mark!

Comment: @dfri Hmm.... actually thinking about it, I agree – given that the answer is basically "*`localClosure` is actually `@escaping`, and there's currently no (non-deprecated) way of marking it as non-escaping*".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Non-parameter closures are `@escaping`, by default

> *"If `localClosure` is, by default, non-escaping, then why ..."*

Based on the discussion in the comments below (thanks @Hamish), we can state the following facts regarding non-parameter closures<sup>†</sup> in Swift 3.0:

- They are, contrary to what one might believe, `@escaping`, by default. As `@noescape` is deprecated in Swift 3 (see e.g. [Xcode 8 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html) or [Swift evolution proposal SE-0103](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0103-make-noescape-default.md)), this means that non-parameter closures cannot be made non-escaping without making use of deprecated methods.
- As described in [the following evolution thread](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160822/026711.html), the lack of `@noescape` attribute for non-parameter closures is a missing feature (somewhat of a regression as this was not a limitation in Swift 2.2), but one that is not necessarily to be implemented in the future (if I'm to understand the answer by Apple dev. Jordan Rose in the linked evolution thread).
- We may however (still) apply the deprecated `@noescape` attribute to a non-parameter closure to make it non-escaping, but will then notably be prompted with an incorrect warning (as below, emphasis mine), which has now been reported as a bug by @Hamish, see [bug report SR-2969](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2969).

  > *"`@noescape` **is default** and is deprecated"*

To summarize, `localClosure` is `@escaping`, which naturally means it cannot be allowed to wrap the non-escaping closure parameter `closure` of `test(...)`.

<sub>[†] By non-parameter closures, I refer to all closures that are *not* parameters to a function, i.e., closures that are *not* supplied to a function as an argument.</sub>

---

As a side-note, which you possibly already knows given your question: we may naturally mark `closure` as `@escaping` if we'd wish to process/wrap it as in your example.

```
func test(closure: @escaping () -> ()) -> () -> () {
    let escapingLocalClosure = { closure() }
    return escapingLocalClosure
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so basically if I assign a closure to a local variable, the compiler assumes that it *might* outlive the function it's in, effectively making it escaping. It's a shame it can't deduce how it's used, as I think that the original example should be allowed. Maybe in the future!

Comment: @dfri Why would the compiler not be able to check if `localClosure` can escape? It can detect if a non-escaping closure parameter can escape (if it's captured by an escaping closure, or stored in a variable that outlives the function call), and will emit an error if it does. Consider [this gist](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/80b2753423e8ee33b562f5ee6d3b4f24) that compiles just fine with the `localClosure` marked as `@noescape` (although it yields a warning about its deprecation). To me, this just looks like a rough edge in the deprecation of `@noescape`, but could well be wrong.

Comment: @Hamish Based on your argument it should indeed be able to infer if `localClosure` can escape, but it seems (given this Q&A) that it, currently, cannot. W.r.t. the gist example: try the same with `@escaping` and you will be prompted with the error message _"`@escaping` may only be applied to parameters of function type"_. Error for `@escaping` and deprecation warning prompt for `@noescape`: I would say this is some kind of ambiguity   w.r.t. escaping/nonescaping of local scope closures (w.r.t. to their "owning" scopes). I believe also the `@noescape` should yield and error in this use case.

Comment: ... or all such closures such as `localClosure` are `@escaping` as per default? Even thought we may not annotate them as such. Could this be considered somewhat buggy behaviour?

Comment: @dfri But the compiler can detect if `localClosure` can escape, indeed if you try and let it escape (for example now see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/ae0cb30c4e60771a1c21ef80f8188b9c) :) ) – the compiler will emit an error. To me, this shows that the framework is in place for the compiler to be able to treat local variable functions as `@noescape` (by default they are indeed `@escaping` – try returning it without `@noescape`), but it's currently a rough edge (bug?) with the removal of `@noescape` in favour of `@escaping`. IMO, we should allowed to do this.

Comment: @Hamish Thanks for all the feedback; I need pause SO:ing for some hours due to another issue (><), however, so I'll need to come back to this. But **1)** the warning msg prompted for adding (the deprecated!) `@noescape` is, in this case, outright wrong (_"`@noescape` is the default and ..."_) as this is apparently only true for closures that are arguments to functions. **2)** _If_ "local" closures such as `localClosure` are indeed intended to be `@escaping` by default, the isn't the deprec. of `@noescape` premature? E.g. the OP:s example shows just such a use case for the `@noescape`. Thanks!

Comment: @dfri Yup, both of your points are spot on. The warning message on the `@noescape` attribute for `localClosure` is completely bogus, as [SE-0103](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0103-make-noescape-default.md) only made `@noescape` the default for function closure arguments ([this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433221/why-do-closures-require-an-explicit-self-when-theyre-all-non-escaping-by-defa) may also be relevant). I also definitely think that the Swift team were premature in deprecating the `@noescape` attribute, as it still has clear use cases.

Comment: What's really interesting is that in Swift 2.3, you couldn't even mark local variable functions as `@noescape`, which means that the Swift team have simultaneously allowed using `@noescape` in this context, and deprecated it :P I'll start writing up a bug report to see what the Swift team make of this.

Comment: Filed two bug reports – [one for the bogus warning](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2969) & one for the regression on [being able to mark local variable closures as `@noescape`](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2970) :)

Comment: @Hamish Nice! I updated my previously quite errorounous answer, thanks for your feedback and discussion :) note that the [evolution thread answer by Jordan Rose](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160822/026711.html) possibly hints that the Swift team is aware about the fact that non-parameter closures may no longer (legally) be non-escaping, but it seems as if they don't really see this as an issue.

Comment: @dfri Happy to help :) (I now just need to figure out which, if any, of my comments I should now delete :P). Also thanks for linking to that evolution thread answer, although it's a shame that the Swift team may not consider re-adding `@noescape` to the language – but I guess we'll have to wait and see how the evolution for Swift 4 plays out.